# Grouping Data In Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm moving a project from MySQL to MSSQL. And since I have a non-standard use of grouping on the Mssql side, I can't bring up the correct data. I need a suggestion. The stok_adet field displays the wrong data. How can we overcome this? Thank you in advance for your help.

My current screenshots are as follows.

Mssql Query

```
SELECT sm.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM stok_durum d
        WHERE sm.stok_durum_id = sm.stok_durum_id
       ) as stok_adet
FROM (SELECT s.*, m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali 
                                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM stok s 
      CROSS JOIN mermer_cins m 
      WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1 
ORDER BY sm.blok_no ASC, sm.bundle_no ASC, sm.stok_tarih DESC
```

MySql side

```
SELECT Count(*) AS stok_adet, s.*, m.*,d.*
FROM stok AS s 
CROSS JOIN mermer_cins AS m 
JOIN stok_durum AS d ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id 
WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali 
ORDER BY s.blok_no ASC, s.bundle_no ASC, s.stok_tarih DESC
```

MsSql side

[image: related result]

MySql side

[image: related result]

Comment: You could try explaining what you are trying to achieve as well as sqlserver code which doesn't work an the dubious MySQL code.Also we cannot do anything with images sample data ane expected output as text would help

Answer (score 0):

When calculating stok_adet you have a comparison between the same column:

```
   WHERE sm.stok_durum_id = sm.stok_durum_id
```

but you maybee want:

```
   WHERE d.stok_durum_id = sm.stok_durum_id
```

Try:

```
SELECT sm.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM stok_durum d
        WHERE d.stok_durum_id = sm.stok_durum_id
       ) as stok_adet
FROM (SELECT s.*, m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali 
                                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM stok s 
      CROSS JOIN mermer_cins m 
      WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1 
ORDER BY sm.blok_no ASC, sm.bundle_no ASC, sm.stok_tarih DESC
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but' stock_adet ' yields still come in the wrong number.
[![related result][1]][https://i.ibb.co/wBmZJvj/mssqlside-stok-adet-problem.png]

Comment: Please provide an example data for stok, stok_durum and mermer_cins tables.